# For what values are these logarithms true?

Tags: logarithms

For what values, x and y, are both these equations true?

$$\frac {\log(x)}{\log(y)} = \frac 23$$

AND

$$\frac xy = \frac 23$$

How would one solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equation can be rewritten as
$$\ln x = {2\over 3}\,\ln y$$
or
$$x = e^{\ln x} = e^{2/3 \ln y} = \left( e^{\ln y}\right)^{2/3} = y^{2/3}.$$
Substituting this into the second equation yields
$$y^{-1/3} = {y^{2/3} \over y} = {2\over3},$$
so $\displaystyle y^{1/3} = {3\over2}$ and $\displaystyle y=\left(3\over2\right)^3={27\over 8}$.
Then $\displaystyle x={2\over3}\cdot y = {2\over3}\cdot{27\over 8} = {9\over 4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.
Notice that, if $x,y> 0$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\log x}{\log y} &= \frac{2}{3}\\
\log x &=\frac{2}{3}\log y\\
\log x &= \log \left(y^{2/3}\right)
\end{align*}
and 
$$x =  \frac{2}{3}y.$$